# How to get a string from an XSL 3.0 Map

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have an XSL Map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"  
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map">
    
    <xsl:param name="settings" select="'https://testurl.com' ||  '/_resources/includes/settings.xml'"/>
    
    <xsl:template name="sidenav">
        <map key="style" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="doc-available($settings)">
                    <string key="navcss" select="doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='section-menu-type']"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <string key="navcss" select="$nav-css"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </map>
        "style" : <xsl:value-of select="map:get('style')('navcss')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:call-template name="sidenav"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to get the value with the below code I get: "Fatal Error: Unknown type map"

```
"style" : <xsl:value-of select="map:get('style')('navcss')"/>
```

If I substitute it with this:

```
<xsl:variable name="map" select="map {
    'navcss' : if(doc-available($settings)) then doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='section-menu-type'] else 'd3',            
}"/>
<xsl:value-of select="map:get($map, 'navcss')"/>
```

I get the value.  My question is, can you create a map element and get its key similar to the map function, or do you just have to use the map xpath function?

Comment: The XSLT 3 spec and the XPath 3.1 functions spec defines a `map` element in the function  namespace, it is meant primarily to be used in the XML representation of JSON that `json-to-xml` outputs or `xml-to-json` consumes as its input. So while XSLT can have a literal result element named `map` in the function namespace I don't understand why you expect that to be accessible with `map:get('style')`, that function expect an XDM map as its first argument, then a property a its second.

Comment: I had tried replacing @key in the top map element for @name='style' and then <xsl:value-of select="map:get($style, 'navcss')" but couldn't get it to work.  I thought that it would be the same thing since both the map element and map function have the same type.

Comment: I wanted to create the map element to eliminate having to query whether a file is available multiple times within the xpath expression. e.g.: ```<xsl:variable name="style" select="map {'navcss' : if(doc-available($settings)) then doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='navcss'] else 'd3', 
'navtype' : if(doc-available($settings)) then doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='navtype'] else 'section-nav', 
'navcategories' : if(doc-available($settings)) then doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='navcategories'] else 'true' }"/>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML representation of JSON defined in XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 uses such a `map` element to represent JSON objects and you can convert such XML to JSON with `xml-to-json` and feed it to `parse-json`; on the other hand to create a map in XSLT 3.0 I would suggest to use the `xsl:map` and `xsl:map-entry` elements or to simply use XPath 3.1 expressions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="json-xml">
      <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
          <string key="foo">bar</string>
          <number key="pi">3.1415927</number>
      </map>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:variable name="map1" select="xml-to-json($json-xml) => parse-json()"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="map2" as="map(*)">
      <xsl:map>
          <xsl:map-entry key="'foo'" select="'bar'"/>
          <xsl:map-entry key="'pi'" select="math:pi()"/>
      </xsl:map>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <section>
          <h2>Example</h2>
          <p>{$map1?pi}</p>
          <p>{$map1?foo}</p>
      </section>
      <section>
          <h2>Example</h2>
          <p>{$map2?pi}</p>
          <p>{$map2?foo}</p>
      </section>
  </xsl:template>
```

As for your expression in the comment, it seems you could just use e.g.

```
select="if (doc-available($settings)) 
        then map { 'navcss' : doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='navcss'], 'navtype' :  doc($settings)/document/settings/ouc:div[@label='navtype']}
        else map { 'navcss' : 'd3', 'navtype' : 'sectionnav' }"
```

I haven't spelled out all map properties but I hope it is clear how to list further properties there.